# Android inclue one layout in another, with minor changes to the includee

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a complex table (2x4 grid) defined in xml that I'd like to reuse in another layout, and ive sorted out how using an include tag. In the original usage of the table, however, I explicitly set the color for each text field in my table to a bright green, for high contrast. In the second usage, the table appears against a white background, so I'd like to redefine the color to black. I'll also want to redefine the background.

I see that it's possible to overwrite layout parameters from the include tag, but I don't think background counts as a layout parameter, and I see no way at all to change the text color of every text field in my table. So how would you attack this?

Comment: I suggest looking into setting a theme for the table. Then you can create two different themes with each background color. I am not 100% certain about the details, so I won't post an answer. I just want to make this as a suggestion so you can do further research.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think you can override the theme in an include tag.  I've never tried, but the docs says nothing about it (they do say you can override layout_ parameters).

Comment: You will most likely have to set the theme directly on the table programatically. In fact, you can change the background color of the table programatically without using a theme.

Comment: Ok, seems like there's no super elegant way to do this (like, set a local tag in the topmost xml and refer to it in the text fields below), but defining styles and setting them programmatically ain't bad. Thanks.